# Computing Fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

$a,b,c\in S^2$ and $X$ is a quotient space that make these three points as the same. Computing its fundamental group.

Comment: I believe it is homotopic to $S^1\vee S^1\vee S^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give $X$ a CW complex structure, we will first visualize the following construction: start with three vertices, $a,b,c$. Then, attach three 1-cells, one joining each pair of vertices. This gives you a sort of triangle (topologcally a circle). Attach two 2-cells to the triangle in the obvious way. You have just created a sphere! Now join the three vertices together. This is $X$. It should now be clear that to construct $X$ as a CW complex directly, we should start with a single vertex, and join three one cells to it, forming a wedge of three circles. Finally, join two 2-cells to the one cells in the obvious way. This gives the $CW$ structure on $X$.

In order to develop a CW structure on more complicated spaces, look at how they are defined. Often times, these spaces, especially manifolds, are formed by gluings of simpler shapes. Quotient maps can be thought of, as in this example identifying $n-$cells at various stages of construction.

Comment: so $X$ 's fundamental group is $Z*Z*Z$ right?

Comment: I'm afraid its a bit more complicated than that. When I calculate the fundamental group, I get $\langle u,v,w|uvw\rangle$.

Comment: do we have some algorithsm to know whether two fundamental $<A|R>,<A|M>$group are isomorphic

Comment: What you are describing is the famous and frustrating [word problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups), whose solution is that no such algorithm exists for the general case. Some specific groups  are better understood, but not, regrettably, by me.

Comment: AlexS, Isn't that isomorphic to $\langle u,v\rangle=\Bbb Z*\Bbb Z$? With the isomorphism from your thing to my thing mapping $w$ to $(uv)^{-1}$. @noname1014

Comment: @Akiva Yeah, that seems right to me.

Comment: @AlexS I fell confusing , whose answer is right? also why there is two persons want to close this question? is there some mistake in my question?

Comment: @noname1014 Both answers are right. The groups are isomorphic. I think people are voting to close the question based on the recent edits which make it sound like you are asking people to do your homework for you. The original question was better, in my opinion.